# PHP - [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, xml, xls

I've programmed a website wich loads an external XML with XLST to HTML formatting.
It works perfectly testing it on MAMP. But when I install the website on the clients server I get this error:

DOMDocument::load(url to the external xml file) [domdocument.load]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

This is the script I use to load the XML/XSLT.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('url to external XML file');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load(get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/agenda/stylesheet.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

I tried checking if the Fopen is enables... and it is on? So what would be the problem?

Comment: You don't have permission to load the external XML file.  Either alter the permissions on the file or get someone who can do so to do so.

Comment: the php.ini setting `allow_url_fopen` is disabled. enable it or try with cURL. See these for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+stream+permission+denied

Comment: @Gordon allow_url_fopen is on...

Comment: @Gordon what would be the script to load with curl?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the file is writable, not in use (open by another process), and that you have permissions to access it.

You can change it in most FTP clients (Change permissions, you should set the number to `0777`.)

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but with file are you pointing to? the xml or the xls? de XML is on a remote server..I don't have access to.

Comment: +1 Easy solution to an easy problem. For mac users using localhost, right-click the xml file->get info->Sharing and permissions